# Use terraform reference variable inside double quotes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

How can I pass a variable inside double quotes?

I have a variable defined as:

```
env = "development"
```

Now, I am not able to pass this variable like below:

```
"Condition": "Environment is var.env"
```

It should assign "Environment is development"

While I am able to pass if I only use `var.env` like below:

```
"Condition": var.env
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable interpolation syntax like so:

```
"Environment is ${var.env}"
```

Comment: I am getting "Error: Reference to undeclared input variable" error while trying to use as "Environment is ${var.env}". 
I am using .tfvars file as referenced in this link in No. 3 
https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/i-tried-4-different-ways-to-assign-variable-in-terraform/

Comment: You haven't defined the variable previously that is why it's complaining.

Comment: I know, by ${var.env}, it is expecting me to define as input variable ->
variable "env" {
   type        = string
   default     = "development"
}
but in this case I need to use .tfvars and define as env = "development"

Comment: You are failing to see the difference between variable declaration (the definition you mention) and assigning a value to a variable that has been defined (the part with .tfvars).

Comment: Marko is correct. You define the variable (as you outlined in your previous comment), then you also need to provide a value for that variable (as you have done in the tfvars). Both are required.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Marko E and Ben Whaley. Defining a variable "env" worked.